# Is there any significance to Captain Picard's baldness?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Was the fact that Captain Picard has no hair just a random artefact of the fact that Patrick Stewart was the best/chosen actor for the role?

Or was the choice of Patrick Stewart influenced in any way by the fact that the show creators/casters preferred the bald look for some reason **before** Stewart was cast?

I'm looking for authoritative info, not guesses.

Comment: No guesses? Aww, darn.

Comment: Nobody going to do the baldly going joke?

Comment: @Wikis: Something like "to baldly go where no man has gone before..."

Comment: @TGnat: that's the one...

Comment: God only made so many perfect heads... the rest of you he put hair on :)

Comment: Having no hair would reduce Picard's aerodynamic drag, so he could move faster around planets with atmospheres.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It look like Patrick Stewart's baldness was a point against him when he was cast as Captain Picard. From [Memory alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Patrick_Stewart) :

> In the early pre-production stage of the series, TNG producer Robert H. Justman wanted Stewart for the role of Data. (Patrick Stewart: The Unauthorized Biography)
>   [...]
>   Stewart was invited to read for the part of Jean-Luc Picard after Robert Justman saw him during Shakespeare readings at a lecture at UCLA. **Gene Roddenberry's first thought was that he "can't put a bald head man in the captain's chair".** (TNG Season 1 DVD special feature "The Beginning")

Comment: Patrick Stewart as Data?! What?!

Comment: @Plutor That would have lead to the question : How an androids could go bald?

Comment: @DavRob60: A bald headed android, looks like this `[bug]`...\*puts.sunglasses.on\*...is `[status-by-design]`. *YYYEEEAAAAHHHHHH*...

Comment: @DavRob60 And hair on an android makes MORE sense?

Answer (score 32):

In this [video interview](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcU222mT5JE), Patrick Stewart is asked about the topic. He recalls a reporter asking the question to Gene Roddenberry.

> *"Surely by the 24th century, they would have found a cure for male
>   pattern baldness?"* *And Gene Roddenberry said **"No, by the 24th
>   century, no one will care"**.*

Comment: Gene was so right. Plus...I've seen or read (not sure which) an interview with Stewart in which he explains that wigs were tried on him, but he simply looked like a bald guy in a wig, so they let him be natural.

Comment: They learned their lesson from Shatner, I guess.

Comment: It is hilarious that Roddenberry said this in light of the accepted answer.

Comment: @jpmc26, Roddenberry didn't live in the 24th century.