# Did Patrick Stewart wear a toupee for his The Next Generation audition?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

As Ray [says](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120662/when-did-patrick-stewart-appear-in-star-trek-with-hair/120663?noredirect=1#comment296186_120663) on my other question:

> BOTH pictures present him with fake hair. Initially, the producers didn't want a bald captain, so they issued Patrick Stewart a toupee. I don't know when, why and how this idea changed.

But I can't find anything to substantiate it.

On [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14166/is-there-any-significance-to-captain-picards-baldness) Marian [says](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14166/is-there-any-significance-to-captain-picards-baldness#comment60395_15641):

> Gene was so right. Plus...I've seen or read (not sure which) an interview with Stewart in which he explains that wigs were tried on him, but he simply looked like a bald guy in a wig, so they let him be natural.

But no one has a reference.

Memory Alpha only says that he wore it for a [flashback](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/File:Picard_with_hair.jpg).

The only other reference I found about it is [here](http://www.trekbbs.com/threads/stargazer-picards-hair.175336/) but nothing conclusive.

Did he wear a toupee for his audition?

Answer (score 20):

### Yes.

According to [this site](http://shatnerstoupee.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/gene-roddenberry-i-dont-want-bald-man.html) (emphasis mine):

> A revealing comment made by Gene Roddenberry in an interview shortly before his death. In the December 1991 issue of *Cinefantastique* magazine (which also provided us with [this](http://shatnerstoupee.blogspot.nl/2009/11/150th-post-more-on-moving-story.html)) the *Star Trek* creator recalled how in 1986 producer Robert Justman had found a British actor called Patrick Stewart whom he believed could be the new captain of the *Enterprise* in *Star Trek: The Next Generation*:
>
> > "[Bob Justman] had gone to UCLA and had seen this man he wanted as Picard. He presented him to me, and my first reaction was 'Jesus Christ, Bob. I don't want bald man. In his wisdom, Justman kept his mouth shut and let me grow accustomed to him."
>
> In fact, **Roddenberry asked Patrick Stewart to wear a toupee in his audition for *Star Trek: The Next Generation***. He did, but in the end, balder heads prevailed.

This is confirmed - about as canonically as it possibly could be - in the following interview with producer Rick Berman, in which Berman tells the story of how Stewart had his theatrical wig sent over from England to wear for his final audition for the role of Captain Picard:

Comment: There's no transcript but Steward goes into it in some detail himself in the Nerdist podcast http://nerdist.com/nerdist-podcast-sir-patrick-stewart-returns/

Comment: _"balder heads prevailed"_ ^_^ ^_^

Comment: To baldly go ...

Answer (score 13):

I mentioned this in comments on the other question, but this incident is described in the documentary *Chaos on the Bridge*.  Here is a quote from a review of this documentary:

> Roddenberry then reportedly agreed to listen to Stewart read for the role, on the condition that he wear a wig. The actor’s wig was later sent via FedEx from England to Los Angeles. Stewart first read his lines with the wig on and then he was called in to read the lines again, but this time without the wig. After his audition the actor was selected to play Captain Picard in the TV series and Roddenberry addressed all concerns about the actor by saying “hair doesn’t mean anything in the 25th century.”

http://www.ibtimes.com/william-shatners-star-trek-documentary-reveals-how-being-bald-almost-made-patrick-1993413